# How to persist the value of label after using getElementById() javascript function in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my code --

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"         Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfirst() {
        document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = "abc";
        document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML;

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="myfirst()" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After running this code i get the output perfectly on the label
i.e text of label1 gets change but again it is assigned to its original "value" after page is refreshed.
Infact, i want to persist its value to "abc" after page is refreshes.

Comment: Solved myself...and thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain variables through refresh, page loads, and post back you will want to use JS **session or local storage**. As a page loads, it will grab the HTML that the server spits out, and other than the file caching, it will have no memory of last time the page was visited. But if you use [session or local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and load the variables from there (and set them there), then it will maintain after refresh.

Now, I'm assuming your situation is more complex than the sample you posted. If so, you will want a function that calls when the document finishes loading

**Example In Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     <insert your code to check session variable here>
});
```

to load the values if they exist, and when the values are modified, you will want to store them to the local storage

So using this situation as an example, you would create a session variable to say if the button has been clicked. You would check this on load. If it has been clicked, then set the text to abc, if the variable doesn't exist, or it hasn't been clicked, then do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your label just changes to "ABC" when you click Submit button. To automatically change to ABC, you should add that event to `<body onload='myfirst()'>` you can use ViewState or Session to store ABC when submitting form

```
function myfirst(){document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = <%: Session["NAME"].ToString()%>;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Label control renders to a html span element. However, only html input based controls maintain their state during postback. These are your traditional asp.net controls like `TextBox`, `Checkbox`, and, `DropDownlist`; in a traditional http form they translate to `input` with `type="text"`, `input` with `type="checkbox"`, and the `select` element, respectively.

However if you still want a functionality like that you'd need a composite control. This control should expose some javascript api to update the span element and an input hidden field. The control as such should assign the value in the hidden field before it renders response back to client.